# ASP inline password?

Tags: asp-classic, passwords

I am not very familiar with hacking techniques and safety vulnerabilities, but I am starting to worry a little bit about our site's security, which is built on ASP Classic, running IIS 7.5

We use ASP inline authentication. Inside the ASP file I have the username and password set up.  I have restricted the access to a certain username to a specific IP address (the username used by employees) and the other usernames use a confirmation password received by SMS on the phone.

1. Is the IP based auth safe? I've heard of entering a certain IP address through certain ports and thus gaining access from that certain IP address.
2. Can the content of the ASP file get hacked and read?
3. When generating the SMS, the ASP script opens a link through XMLHTTP 'https://generate.sms-company-domain.com/?password=&acount=&message=Your confirmation password is '. Could somebody listen to the URL that are called and easily get the SMS password?
4. Can you think of any vulnerabilities of our log in methods?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your 3rd point is looks like problem if URL expose in that way any one can read password or information via some tools like fiddler.

for protect your site from hacking please make sure 
1) you site used SQL injection technique
2) all important data submit via post method.
3) need to take care of Cross site scripting attack like when someone load page it save one encrypted value in cookie and in code read that cookie value so we can confirm that page is not calling from some other place.